# subject complement or adverb phrase

Tags: prepositional-phrases, complements

I have a question about a sentence below.

> we expect about 50% of registered voters to vote in the election.

Is a PP(in the election) a subject complement(is it possible?) or a modifier?

If it is a modifier, does it modify a verb(vote)?

While searching out it, I happened upon a sentence and relating explanation

He was selected (as) chairman.

In this case, was isn’t a linking verb. However, some answered my question like the following.

"Chairman is a subject complement."

So I can’t understand why it is a subject complement.

Comment: @BillJ one for you...

Comment: It seems that it could be useful in respect to the verb *select*  https://m.facebook.com/384068241982602/posts/factitive-verbs-what-is-a-factitive-verbfactitive-verbs-are-used-to-indicate-the/1316309672091783/

Comment: The Predicative Complement : http://www.ello.uos.de/field.php/Syntax/TGPredCompl

Answer (score 2):

> *We expect about 50% of registered voters* [*to vote in the election*].

It’s not a complement but a modifier. The PP "in the election" is an adjunct in clause structure, i.e. it modifies "vote".

The whole sentence is a catenative construction in which the bracketed subordinate infinitival clause is complement of the catenative verb "expect". The intervening NP "about 50% of registered voters" is the syntactic object of "expect" and the *understood* (semantic) subject of the subordinate clause.

> *He was selected (as) chairman.*

In this passive construction the 'bare role' NP “chairman” is predicative complement in that it relates to a predicand, here the subject “he”. “As” is optional”: if it is included the PP “as chairman” is called a marked predicative complement and "chairman" is called a predicative oblique because it is related to the verb via the preposition "as".